# Who said "You can kill a man but you can't kill an idea"?

Tags: quotes

> **You can kill a man but you can't kill an idea**

Goodreads.com [referenced](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/94983-you-can-kill-a-man-but-you-cant-kill-a) the quote to the **Greek philosopher Sophocles**.

where

Brainyquote.com [referenced](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/m/medgarever101375.html) the quote to **Medgar Evers.**.

Who did said this quote? Valid sources (like books, papers) would convince me.

Comment: Maybe both said it?

Comment: I have searched the [translated works of Sophocles](http://classics.mit.edu/Browse/browse-Sophocles.html) and couldn't find it (which doesn't prove I didn't miss it, or it might be differently translated.)

Comment: On page 297, the book *[The Autobiography of Medgar Evers: A Hero's Life and Legacy Revealed Through His Writings, Letters, and Speeches](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=U9DsBWEzKMUC&lpg=PA45&ots=7gKrlyCI7P&dq=Medgar%20Evers%20transcript%20-college&pg=PA297)* quotes Mississippi Governor Ronnie Musgrove attributing the words to Evers in a 2002 speech.

Comment: ^^^ These aren't definitive enough for an answer, but I don't know how to get better.

Comment: I'd like to point out that this statement applies to good and evil, not just good. You can kill terrorists but not the idea of terrorism.

Comment: Indeed, both could have said it.
And yes, it's ambiguous. Thanks for the addition.

@Oddthinking haha that's true. I think it was even mentioned in the movie "V for Vendetta"...

Anyhow, If anyone knows something concrete, don't hesitate to comment

Comment: They rewrote most of *V for Vendetta* (i.e. mostly the same same story but using different words/dialog) for the movie. I prefer (recommend) the novel i.e. Alan Moore's writing. The movie version is, "Beneath this mask there is more than flesh. Beneath this mask there is an idea, Mr. Creedy. And ideas are bulletproof." The original version, "There, did you think to kill me? There's no flesh or blood within this cloak to kill. There's only an idea. Ideas are bulletproof. Farewell."

Comment: No answer on http://quoteinvestigator.com/ either...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least the sentiment if not the exact phrasing pre-dates Medgar Evers (who lived from 1925 to 1963).

---

From a book titled *The Russian Pendulum* by Arthur Bullard published by Macmillan in 1919,

> The armies of Tchaikovsky, Denikin, and Kolchak may enter Moscow and hang a few hundred of the Bolshiviki, but that will not kill the idea.

---

Or from *Life* magazine in 1951,

> The fact is that he was out to destroy the ideas that Churchill stood for. He has told me many times: it is ideas he wants to kill, not men, but in order to kill the idea it is necessary to attack the man.

---

The Dublin Review (Page 260) Nicholas Patrick Wiseman - 1845

> You may kill a few individuals, but you cannot kill an idea. An idea is immortal. In the midst of tempests an idea attains the stature of a giant, and like a diamond shines with a new light at every repercussion.

---

The Mining Congress Journal (Page 446) - 1920

> These thirty-seven murders are the natural result of such sentiments as have been expressed by the sensational press in defining its attitude toward so- called radicalism. Their slogan has been "You cannot kill an idea."

---

Vanity Fair (Page 20) - 1915

> You may kill a man, but you cannot kill an idea, and nationality is the most vital sort of idea.

Comment: What about Sophocles? I'm also not sure if this proves Medgar Evers said this.

Comment: IMO the question isn't whether he said it, but whether he was the *first* to say it: apparently it was *already* a frequently-published  expression or turn of phrase, by the time he might have used it.